# How can I passing value into the JavaScript function in asp:LinkButton OnClientClick?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I passing value into the javascript function in asp:LinkButton OnClientClick?

Example:
If I have the following code:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="lvTeams" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTeams" DataKeyNames="ReferenceValue"
    OnItemCommand="lvTeams_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <ul style="color:#fe8113;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
      </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return multipleTeamsAllowedValidation()" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="" CssClass="orange"
          Text='<%# Eval("TeamName")%>' />
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

How can I pass the value `<%# Eval("ReferenceValue")%>` into the JavaScript function `multipleTeamsAllowedValidation()`in the `asp:LinkButton OnClientClick` event??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
onclick= 'multipleTeamsAllowedValidation(<%# Eval("SHOW_Name") %>);'
```

or

You can try out this.Value or this.InnerText to pass the value to html function

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return 
multipleTeamsAllowedValidation(this.InnerText)" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="" 
CssClass="orange" Text='<%# Eval("TeamName")%>' />
```

or

you can pass object itself by passing this

```
OnClientClick="return multipleTeamsAllowedValidation(this)"
```

than you can able to access the text of it easily and than do the perform operation.

in function do  `document.getElementById(this.Id).innerText or this.innerText`

Comment: @Jin Yong  - try second option pass this as fuction agrument and tha do get access to text of it.

Comment: this is working but what I wanna it to be get is the value from DataKeyNames (<%# Eval("ReferenceValue")%>) instead of the innerText

Comment: @Jin Yong = try the first option that I pasted

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, its a lot better to write a small helper.

Markup.

```
OnClientClick='<%# SetClientClick(Eval("ReferenceValue")) %>'>
```

Code-behind

```
protected string SetClientClick(object objName)
{
    return String.Format("javascript:return multipleTeamsAllowedValidation('{0}');", objName.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a another easy way,

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRecord" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("TeamName","javascript:return multipleTeamsAllowedValidation({0});") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

You can also hit the link below-

https://snavin.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/pass-eval-value-in-javascript-function-from-gridview/

I hope this would've you.